# Using regex to find (and replace) phone number extensions (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently trying to find phone number extensions from pandas series, an example being 'Ext: 123'. The extension can be in the cell either on its own (like previously) or after a phone number, e.g. 123 456 789 / Ext: 4502.

The extensions can also be in varying formats, such as Ex.430 (missing the letter t, no space after punctuation mark. Therefore, I wanted to find all sequences in the series that have 1-3 letters, followed by zero or more symbols, zero or more spaces, followed by 2 to 6 numbers.

Optimally, I would also replace these with the correct format, which is ***Ext: 32*** (can be up to 6 numbers)

Here is my regex so far:

`({'\D{1,3}\W*\s*\d{2,6}]'`

I have also used other variations, but those didn't work either.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: are these US based phone numbers?

Comment: The phone numbers are from all over the world.

Comment: How clean are the numbers?  In other words are there still dashes, periods, and parenthesis hanging around?

Comment: You can do some fine tuning and e.g. replace the `\D` by `[^\d \n]`

Comment: The numbers are cleansed at this point. Only numbers, spaces and forward slashes remain

Comment: @MichaelButscher Sorry can you explain the rationale behind the line break?

Comment: Probably it isn't needed, I tried the regex with multiple lines in regex101 but for a dataframe with one line per row you can omit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the column on alphabet characters (plus colon).

```
df['phones'].str.split(r'[A-Za-z:]+\.?', expand=True)
```